# Use Athena SQL to get a value from JSON key

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I need to get the email address from this 'facets' table I created from my firehose logs (JSON).

Now, I am using Athena to get particular information.

I need to get the email addresses from this:

This is my out of 'facets' when I pass-

```
SELECT * FROM "sampledb"."facets" limit 10
```

> {email_channel={mail_event={mail={message_id=oadfosadu6237864237615, message_send_timestamp=1622696691764, from_address=abcd@jk.com, destination=[abcd@jk.com], headers_truncated=false, headers=[{name=From, value=abcd@jk.com}, {name=To, value=abcd@jk.com}, {name=MIME-Version, value=1.0}], common_headers={from=ghjk@li.com, to=[abcd@jk.com]}}, send={}, rendering_failure=null}}}

Comment: Can you post the source JSON record and DDL ?

Comment: What is the expected output from "this"?

Comment: I want the email addresses out of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have one column which stores json in provided format you can use `json_extract` with needed paths (and maybe some casts):

```sql
with dataset1 as (
    select * from (values(JSON
 '{
   "email_channel": {
      "mail_event": {
         "mail": {
            "message_id": "oadfosadu6237864237615",
            "message_send_timestamp": 1622696691764,
            "from_address": "abcd@jk.com",
            "destination": [
               "abcd@jk.com"
            ],
            "headers_truncated": false,
            "headers": [
               {
                  "name": "From",
                  "value": "abcd@jk.com"
               },
               {
                  "name": "To",
                  "value": "abcd@jk.com"
               },
               {
                  "name": "MIME-Version",
                  "value": "1.0"
               }
            ],
            "common_headers": {
               "from": "ghjk@li.com",
               "to": [
                  "abcd@jk.com"
               ]
            }
         },
         "send": {},
         "rendering_failure": null
      }
   }
}')) as facets(facet))

select
    json_extract(facet, '$.email_channel.mail_event.mail.from_address') mail_from,
    CAST(json_extract(facet, '$.email_channel.mail_event.mail.destination') AS ARRAY(VARCHAR)) destination
from dataset1
```

And output:

| mail_from | destination |
| --- | --- |
| "abcd@jk.com" | {abcd@jk.com} |

Comment: @sameerawsnoob was glad to help!